# Swapping an img src with a function (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, src

I'm trying to swap two imgs in my webpage and can't wrap my head around why this code doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

This is in the HTML file:

```
<img onclick="swap(); "src="LaptopThin.jpg" id="LaptopPicture" />
```

while this is in a seperate javascript file:

```
 function swap()
  {
     var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture').src;
     if (picture === 'LaptopThin.jpg') {
         picture.src = 'ServerRack.jpg';
     } else {
         picture.src = 'LaptopThin.jpg';
     }
```

I changed the code to:

```
      function swap()
  {
     var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture');
     if (picture.src === 'LaptopThin.jpg') {
         picture.src = 'ServerRack.jpg';
     } else {
         picture.src = 'LaptopThin.jpg';
     }
  }
```

and the picture is still not changing at all in the html file. The img stays on Laptopthin.jpg

Comment: what is the output if you print "picture" in the console..?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the `src` property of `picture` because you set `picture` to the `src` property of an element already.

Change these lines:

```
var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture').src;
if (picture === 'LaptopThin.jpg') {
```

to these:

```
var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture');
if (picture.src === 'LaptopThin.jpg') {
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, the `src` property will give the absolute value of the image source not just the value set by the src attribute

```
function swap() {
    var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture');
    if (picture.src.indexOf('LaptopThin.jpg') > -1) {
        picture.src = 'ServerRack.jpg';
    } else {
        picture.src = 'LaptopThin.jpg';
    }
}
```

---

Another option to try is to use getAttribute

```
function swap() {
    var picture = document.getElementById('LaptopPicture');
    if (picture.getAttribute('src')== 'LaptopThin.jpg') {
        picture.src = 'ServerRack.jpg';
    } else {
        picture.src = 'LaptopThin.jpg';
    }
}
```